# How to populate database using SQLitePlugin Cordova in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have copied "demo.db" file to /data/data/package_name/databases/ as Gaurav suggested:
    visit: http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

"demo.db" has already created tables(e.g: Projects)

I try to connect to connect to "demo.db" by using SQLitePlugin https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin/

I have installed this plugin as suggested by the developer of this Plugin.

In my .js section, after firing the "deviceready" event, i have done by following:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "my demo", 500000);
db.transaction(function(tx){
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectCode, ProjectDescription) VALUES(?,?)',["Lastly", "fdgsdfgsdg"], function(tx, result){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Projects',[],function(tx, result){
        alert("projects");
        for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
        alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + result.rows.item(i).ProjectId +  "ProjectCode =  " + result.rows.item(i).ProjectCode);
       } 
       hideLoading();
    });
}, function(err) {//error callback function.
    alert("Database is not created.");
    hideLoading();
});
```

In my case, instead of using the imported "demo.db", the SQLitePlugin has created the new database"demo.db" by overriding the imported db. When the insert code is executed,it throw the error,"error:no such tables:Projects". Due to this, error callback function is triggered. Please suggest me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for it. For my case, it was due to version incompatibility of .db file created from sqlite3(via sqliteadmin) and SQLitePlugin. To get rid of it, first i create a "demo.db" and a table by following using SQLitePlugin.

```
var myDb = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "my demo", 50000);
    myDb.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE Projects (ProjectId integer primary key,   ProjectCode varchar(20), ProjectDescription varchar(100 ))');
        });
```

After this, i export this created .db from /data/data/package_name/databases/. After exporting, i paste the exported .db file in assets in eclipse. I import this file to .../databases/ folder as gautam suggested:http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html
Then the real task of populating database begins:

```
   var myDb = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("demo", "1.0", "my demo", 50000);
    myDb.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Projects (ProjectCode, ProjectDescription) VALUES(?,?)',["Lastly", "fdgsdfgsdg"], function(tx, result){
                    alert("go");
                    hideLoading();
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Projects',[],function(tx, result){
                        for (var i=0; i<result.rows.length; i++){
                            alert("Row = " + i + " ID = " + result.rows.item(i).ProjectId + "ProjectCode =  " + result.rows.item(i).ProjectCode);
                        } 
                    });
                }, function(err) {
                    alert(err.message);
                    alert("Database is not created.");
                    hideLoading();
                });
        });
```

Here, the sqlitePlugin is accessing the imported "demo.db", and the values are inserted into table, Projects.